# Setting a stored name of a value in java

Tags: java, slider

I have created a phidgets program which sends a sensor value over to a server. I am trying to program it in a way which the name of the ports is already stored in my code. For example, if slider is plugged into port 0, it will send over the value slider instead of the port number.

I had it so String sensorName had the name slider however, i have multiple ports. Do i and if so, create an if statement which if String.valueOf(arg0.getIndex()); = 0, the stored value for 0 will = Slider?

```
public void sensorChanged(SensorChangeEvent arg0) {
            // System.out.println(arg0);
                String sensorValue = ""+arg0.getValue();
                String sensorName= String.valueOf(arg0.getIndex()); 
                System.out.println("Slider value is now "+sensorValue);


            String sendResult = sendToServer(sensorValue,sensorName);
            try {
                    System.out.println("Sleeping.... 1 sec");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           System.out.println("Sent to server, result: "+sendResult);
        }
```

Found a solution. I was overcomplicating it too much.

Thanks for the help.

```
if (arg0.getIndex() == 0){
            sensorName = "slider";
        } else if (arg0.getIndex() ==1){
            sensorName = "rotation";
        } else if (arg0.getIndex() ==2){
            sensorName = "motor";
        }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. "Do I and if so..." - do you what? `String.valueOf()` just gives you the usual string representation, so the number 0 will return "0" etc.

Comment: How do i store the value 0 = slider when it returns it from String.valueOf(arg0.getIndex()); and so forth?

Comment: Not sure why you are using `String.valueOf()` at all. And why not use an array that contains all the port names?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (arg0.getIndex() == 0){
                sensorName = "slider";
            } else if (arg0.getIndex() ==1){
                sensorName = "rotation";
            } else if (arg0.getIndex() ==2){
                sensorName = "motor";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an array?

```
private static String sensorNames = { "slider", "rotation", "motor" };

...
sensorName = sensorNames[arg0.getIndex()];
```

This solution is good if your numbers are small, start from zero, and don't have gaps, or at least, not too many gaps.

This also allows you to change the mapping dynamically (that is, if you plug a sensor to a different port the next time you run).